# Rails searches using querys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tiny-tds

I'm trying to perform a search of records in rails using a query using "Like" to find records similar to those that the user entered in the field, and so far works me wonderfully, the problem comes when I try to search for dates using the "like" ", Giving me two drawbacks:

1. When placing the query to the model, and without even having done the search, stop showing me those records that have no date, showing me only those who have
2. When trying to search the records, the search result does not return any records even if there is one with the same date sent as a parameter

This is the query that I try to do the searches with:

(The "FechaI" field is datetime)

```
  def self.promociones(params)
    query = query.where("(FechaI LIKE :FechaInicial or :FechaInicial = '')",{FechaInicial: "%#{(params[:FechaI_param].try(:to_date)).try(:strftime,"%Y-%m-%d")}%"}) 
    query
  end
```

This is my `index` action:

```
@promos = Listaprom.promociones(params)
```

Comment: `FechaI` is a datetime field at database level, isn't it?

Comment: you see, comparison between datetime fields require that the time field should also match

Comment: @FedeBonisconti Is correct, the "FechaI" field is of type datetime

Comment: @Alfie Is it necessary to enter the time? Even if you use the like?